# Pair of python processes communication

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, server

I need to implement 2 python processes:

1. a python client process that will connect to a https server on the web
2. a python server process that will server 1 or 2 clients (UIs) over ssh if client is outside network, or just tcp if client is inside LAN.

Info will flow from 1 to 2 only, then 2 will communicate back/forth with its clients. 1 will communicate back/forth with https server and pass info to 2.
2 is a sort of slave of 1. 2 can still run if 1 is down but can provide no info to its clients. 1 can run on its own, but it's important to have the UI look at what's going in 1 (through 2).
if 2 crashes, 1 still runs and that's very important.

Looking at the std lib, i see a number of modules that can help.

1. socketserver
2. multiprocessing
3. subprocess
4. ssh (nothing in stdlib)

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You may be best advised to do this using a **Message Queue** - it will give you a very

1. scalable
2. secure
3. web interface
4. SSL supported

I would suggest that you have a look at RabbitMQ - there is a lovely Python 3.x interface with it.

You could of course do this with TCP Sockets also - but why not let the MQ handle the nasty synchronisation stuff - and you can concentrate on implementing the business processes.